# Using windows forms charts in Blazor server app

Tags: winforms, .net-core, blazor

I started a new Blazor Server App .Net Core 3.1 and wanted to re-use some old code from
my previous WindowsForms App which generates PDF file with stacked chart.

Most of the code runs ok until it hit the AddChartV2() function:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
private void AddChartV2()
{

            DateTime startDate = StartDate;
            DateTime endDate = EndDate;

            //Energy 
            decimal SharpEnergyStart = TenantTouData.AsEnumerable().
            Where(p => p.Field<DateTime>("Date") == startDate).
            Select(p => p.Field<decimal>("Sharp")).FirstOrDefault();

            decimal SharpEnergyEnd = TenantTouData.AsEnumerable().
            Where(p => p.Field<DateTime>("Date") == endDate).
            Select(p => p.Field<decimal>("Sharp")).FirstOrDefault();

            decimal PeakEnergyStart = TenantTouData.AsEnumerable().
            Where(p => p.Field<DateTime>("Date") == startDate).
            Select(p => p.Field<decimal>("Peak")).FirstOrDefault();

            decimal PeakEnergyEnd = TenantTouData.AsEnumerable().
            Where(p => p.Field<DateTime>("Date") == endDate).
            Select(p => p.Field<decimal>("Peak")).FirstOrDefault();

            decimal ValleyEnergyStart = TenantTouData.AsEnumerable().
            Where(p => p.Field<DateTime>("Date") == startDate).
            Select(p => p.Field<decimal>("Valley")).FirstOrDefault();

            decimal ValleyEnergyEnd = TenantTouData.AsEnumerable().
            Where(p => p.Field<DateTime>("Date") == endDate).
            Select(p => p.Field<decimal>("Valley")).FirstOrDefault();

            //Create new chart
            var chartimage = new MemoryStream();
            var PCF = new RegularTimeOverUsegeChart();

            PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Sharp"].Points.AddXY(startDate.ToString("MMM"), SharpEnergyEnd - SharpEnergyStart);
            PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Sharp"].Points[0].Color = Color.Red;
            PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Peak"].Points.AddXY(startDate.ToString("MMM"), PeakEnergyEnd - PeakEnergyStart);
            PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Peak"].Points[0].Color = Color.Gold;
            PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Valley"].Points.AddXY(startDate.ToString("MMM"), ValleyEnergyEnd - ValleyEnergyStart);
            PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Valley"].Points[0].Color = Color.Green;
            PCF.RegularTOU_crt.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;

            

            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
            {
                DataTable PreviousReadings = new DataTable();

                startDate = startDate.AddMonths(-1);
                endDate = endDate.AddMonths(-1);

                startDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);
                endDate = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, 1);

                decimal TotalSharp = 0, TotalPeak = 0, TotalValley = 0;

                PreviousReadings = Database.GetMySQLTable("SELECT * FROM " + ClientNumber + ".`" + TanentNumber + "` where Date='" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' OR Date='" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "';");
                if (PreviousReadings.Rows.Count == 2)
                {
                    TotalSharp = (decimal)PreviousReadings.Rows[1]["Sharp"] - (decimal)PreviousReadings.Rows[0]["Sharp"];
                    TotalPeak = (decimal)PreviousReadings.Rows[1]["Peak"] - (decimal)PreviousReadings.Rows[0]["Peak"];
                    TotalValley = (decimal)PreviousReadings.Rows[1]["Valley"] - (decimal)PreviousReadings.Rows[0]["Valley"];
                }

                PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Sharp"].Points.AddXY(startDate.ToString("MMM"), TotalSharp);
                PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Sharp"].Points[i].Color = Color.Red;
                PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Peak"].Points.AddXY(startDate.ToString("MMM"), TotalPeak);
                PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Peak"].Points[i].Color = Color.Gold;
                PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Valley"].Points.AddXY(startDate.ToString("MMM"), TotalValley);
                PCF.RegularTOU_crt.Series["Valley"].Points[i].Color = Color.Green;
            }

            PCF.RegularTOU_crt.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Tiff);
            iTextSharp.text.Image Chart_image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(chartimage.GetBuffer());
            Chart_image.ScalePercent(45f); //Rescale image by %
            Chart_image.SetAbsolutePosition(10f, 10f); // Set image bottom left
            ElecBill.Add(Chart_image);

        }
```

I coudn't even debug it line by line, the moment the code reaches this method I get the following:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I don't understand what can I do to fix this, the original desktop app is running ok with the same code, this happens only when I trigger the code form the new Blazor app, any thoughts ?

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly or Blazor Server ?

Comment: It is a Blazor Server

Comment: If you reference/use an assembly depending on Windows.Forms, in your projet, the target framedwork should be like this : <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>

Comment: @guy-at-mercator do you mean I should start over using net5.0 instead core 3.1 app ?

Comment: You could add to your csproj file, the item group below. I'm not sure it will help though as it doesn't look like the Charting namespace has been ported to the new windows forms in dotnet core, at least the docs online only go to .net 4.8
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: do you mean I should start over using net5.0 instead core 3.1 app ?  Yes, as the winforms compatibility pack is, as far as I know, only avaiable for .net5.

Comment: @SmithMart seems like there is some progress, now the error is: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: This version http://87.98.252.207/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.zip is a recompilation in net5.0-windows of System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization source code.

Comment: it looks like there is a pre-release version here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/

Comment: Just to add though, going by https://github.com/dotnet/winforms-datavisualization it has been depreciated. so although you might get it working, I'd probably begin the search for a new charting library.

Comment: I decided to go for .net 5 but now I encounter another problem, the chart.SaveImage() is not supported with the nuget you suggested for .net core3.1 so I wanted to try the Maikebing.System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization but I coudn't find how to reffrence this in the C# class, typing "using Maikebing.System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" doesn't work, anyone can help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Guy at Mercator, after referencing this package

```
87.98.252.207/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.zip
```

The code was able to complete all the methods I use, although I have
to manually set all chart parameters which previously I got from the Windows Forms Chart component...